# Get layer coordinates with mouse click ArcMAP 10.2

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, editing

Im trying to get the layer coordinates with a mouse click in ArcMAP. I did this in QGIS and im not finding anything on how to get this working in ArcMAP. Here is the QGIS version:

```
def selectPoint(self):
        self.pointEmitter = QgsMapToolEmitPoint(self.iface.mapCanvas())
        QObject.connect(self.pointEmitter, SIGNAL("canvasClicked(const QgsPoint, Qt::MouseButton)"), self.selectNow)
        self.iface.mapCanvas().setMapTool(self.pointEmitter)
```

---

I got this working by creating a new plugin in plugin wizard and Choosing a "Tool" in the Toolbar.

Comment: You're using QGIS code, it's **not going to work in ArcMap**. Have a read of the Esri post https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000011690 which explains how to do this in an arcpy addin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to do this from ArcPy then you could look at using:

- a [feature set with a Python script tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/modelbuilder/a-quick-tour-of-using-feature-set-and-record-set.htm); or

> Feature sets allow features to be entered interactively and
>   immediately used as input to a model or script.

- a [Python AddIn](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000011690) (as [commented by @MichaelStimson](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/263100/get-layer-coordinates-with-mouse-click-arcmap-10-2#comment417209_263100))

> Python Add-ins give users the ability to create Python written tools
>   that respond to a mouse click.

Comment: i cant find "onMouseDownMap" on the add.in wizard. Is there a way to call that function in a existing add-in?

Comment: @JoséGabriel the AddIn Wizard writes code that includes it.